# Is there any connection between filter in mathematics and signal processing?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, soft-question, definition

The world filter in mathematics is defined as given by: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(mathematics) On the other hand filtering in signal processing is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(signal_processing)

This two definition appears quite different but the question: is there any connection between them even remotely? Specifically, can we say the filtering in signal processing is a subset of "filter" in mathematics? Motivation behind this is that both appears to be a partial ordered set. Any comment would be appreciated.

Comment: What partial ordered set are you considering for the signal processing?

Comment: No it is unrelated. I think the word filter is not too much used in pure maths because convolution appears everywhere in so many different setting, a single name wouldn't be enough. Also in pure maths the result of the convolution is thought as being completely different to the original, there isn't this signal processing idea that filtering is a slight modification

Comment: @Berci As per the http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartiallyOrderedSet.html the partial order set is a very general set which follows the properties: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialOrder.html  All the coefficients of the filter we use in signal processing seems to follow those properties. Yes we have no idea about the existence of the topology and may be that is the question.

Comment: @reuns: I'm not sure I'd say that.  There's the whole technique of mollification where you take the convolution of a function with a smooth function that is "almost" a Dirac delta, resulting in a function which is a "slight modification" of the original function but is smooth.